# Returned null on DataFetchingEnvironment .getUser() in Mutation class

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

Original Question: https://github.com/howtographql/graphql-java/issues/4

```
AuthContext context = env.getContext();
Link newLink = new Link(url, description, context.getUser().getId());
```

I do not get null on context variable, but I get a null on `context.getUser()`

code:https://github.com/howtographql/graphql-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/howtographql/hackernews/Mutation.java
or my code:
https://github.com/JonathanSum/myOwnJavaGraphqlStarterKit/blob/master/src/main/java/com/howtographql/hackernews/Mutation.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of that tutorial, which is now unfortunately very outdated...  I'm working on rewriting it in pure graphql-java (without graphql-java-tools), and this is what I'd recommend you try as well.

For the time being, your issue is very likely either because the browser doesn't send the user ID (in the `Authorization` header) at all or, if it does, it doesn't match the ID in Mongo.

Put a break point in [`createContext` method](https://github.com/JonathanSum/myOwnJavaGraphqlStarterKit/blob/master/src/main/java/com/howtographql/hackernews/GraphQLEndpoint.java#L54) in `GraphQLEndpoint` and inspect what happens.

The tutorial explains the code you need to add to the client to start sending the `Authorization` header, so make sure you followed that. otherwise, just make sure the ID it sends matches what you have in Mongo.

Comment: It is ok. I just checked the doc. The doc is very similar to the tutorial. I will read the doc when I have time. Thx for your hard work anyway. Your tutorial was fun.